# Is it possible to construct a function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ such that $f$ is injective?

Tags: cardinals

this was a true and false question which I mistakenly thought was false.

My reasoning was thus:

Let the function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ be injective. It follows that for every element $x \in \mathbb{R}$, there exists a unique $y \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $f(x)=y$. But this would imply that $|\mathbb{R}| \leq |\mathbb{Z}|$, which is contradiction since $|\mathbb{R}|$ is uncountable and $|\mathbb{Z}|$. Therefore there is no function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ such that $f$ is injective.

Could someone tell me where I went wrong?

Comment: Well, there doesn't exist an injective function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$, for the reasons you said. You should take this up with the grader.

Comment: Nowhere...You are perfectly right.

Comment: Can you repeat the question exactly? "Construct a function ...." is not a true/false question.

Comment: From [How to ask a good question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10144): Your question should be clear without the title. After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. **The title is not the first sentence of your question**, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title.

Answer (score 1):

You have the sides wrong. Saying that $f\colon A\to B$ is a function means that there is a single $b\in B$ such that $(a,b)\in f$ (because $f$ is a subset of $A\times B$; such unique element is denoted by $f(a)$).

The function is injective if, for every $b\in B$ there exists *at most* one element $a\in A$ such that $f(a)=b$. (Note that is quite different from what you're saying.)

There are infinitely many functions $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{Z}$, but none of them is injective. Indeed, as you observe, this would imply that $|\mathbb{R}|\le|\mathbb{Z}|$, so $|\mathbb{R}|=|\mathbb{Z}|$, against the well known fact that $\mathbb{R}$ is not countable.

Comment: Well, we know that every element of $\mathbb{R}$ must have an image—an element $b \in \mathbb{Z}$, so are the two statements not logically equivalent? If you take an arbitrary set, $g: T \rightarrow Z$, since every element of $T$ has an image, and no two images are the same, does it not follow that for every $x \in T$ there exists a unique $y \in Z$ and that this is the same as stating that for every $y \in Z$ there is at most one element $x \in T$ such that $g(x) = y$?

Comment: @BenjaminSakamoto No, they aren't. The function $f\colon\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$ defined by $f(x)=x^2$ certainly satisfies the condition you stated. But it's not injective, is it? You're confusing the definition of function with the injectivity condition. They're different things.

Comment: @BenjaminSakamoto I don't think you're confusing the definition of function with injectivity, instead I think the point egreg is making, is that you're using "unique" incorrectly. The statement "for every $x$ there is a unique $y$ such that $f(x)=y$", means that there exists no $y'\neq y$ such that $f(x)=y'$. You seem to believe that the uniqueness refers to $x$ instead; you want to say that there exists no $x'\neq x$ such that $f(x')=y$. However, the latter must be worded differently than you've done in your question.